# SQL QUERY SYNTAX MYSQL SELECT TWO OR MORE TABLE

Tags: php, sql

hello guys i have a problem to my sql syntax i have two table which selected one is Products and second one is Reviews. problem product that not have review  is not retriving data  from Database only retrieving is have a review details here is my sql QUERY SYNTAX

```
SELECT * FROM products 
INNER JOIN reviews ON products.p_id = reviews.p_id  products.p_id 
WHERE products.service_prom = '{$value}' 
GROUP BY products.p_id  
ORDER BY rand() DESC 
LIMIT 16
```

if i Used this one it works but a product does not have a reviews

```
SELECT * FROM products  
WHERE products.service_prom = '{$value}' 
GROUP BY products.p_id  ORDER BY rand() DESC 
LIMIT 16
```

how can i retrive data from two table with separated query or else single query

here is my table Structures


[image: Here is table or Reviews]
[image: here is the table of Products]

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN. https://ocw.cs.pub.ro/courses/_media/bd/laboratoare/join-types.png?w=500&tok=4a6021

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
LEFT JOIN reviews ON products.p_id = reviews.p_id
WHERE products.service_prom = '{$value}' 
GROUP BY products.p_id  
ORDER BY rand() DESC 
LIMIT 16
```

Also have a look at [this StackOverflow answer to get the difference of the different joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27540786/3840840).

Comment: For reference: [MySql JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
LEFT JOIN reviews ON products.p_id = reviews.p_id
WHERE products.service_prom = '{$value}' 
GROUP BY products.p_id  
ORDER BY rand() DESC 
LIMIT 16
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'products.p_id
WHERE products.service_prom = 'freshipping'
GROUP BY products.' at line 2

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, there were a typo. Please try now